# Changing the position of images on the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface

So I am making this ABC learning game , What I want to do is if I click on the A button more than once then , the three Images will change their position, What I want to do is this
![enter image description here][1]

When I click on A button, the three image will appear on the screen, the first is apple as I set it that way in the loop, but the second two images will appear randomly, though sometimes one o them is apple again, I could fix that.

My Question is, how can I change that position of the Apple to the second and second image to the first and third image to the second position if the "A" button is clicked more than once.
SO, the result will be the apple will change position based on the click "A" button and other two picture changes their position and chosed randomly from the array.

So, here is my code for the JPanel, where everything takes place.Most of the code     is  explained in the comments

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author Dip
 */
public class AbcGeniusPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    //Declare the necessary Variables here
    private JButton[] buttons;  //create an array for buttons
    private BorderLayout layout; //Declare object of BorderLayout
    private Image image = null;
    private boolean showImage = false;
    //Initialize all the variables here
    static int index = 0;
    int randNumber = 0, id = 0;
    int q = 0, w = 0;
    int buttonClick = 0;
    //Store all the imahges that will appear on the screen into an String type array
    private static String[] imageList = {"src/Images/1.png", "src/Images/2.png", "src/Images/3.png", "src/Images/4.png", "src/Images/5.png", "src/Images/6.png", "src/Images/7.png", "src/Images/8.png", "src/Images/9.png", "src/Images       /10.png",
        "src/Images/11.png", "src/Images/12.png", "src/Images/13.png", "src/Images         /14.png", "src/Images/15.png",
        "src/Images/16.png", "src/Images/17.png", "src/Images/18.png", "src/Images         /19.png", "src/Images/20.png",
        "src/Images/21.png", "src/Images/22.png", "src/Images/23.png", "src/Images          /24.png", "src/Images/25.png",
        "src/Images/26.png"
    };

    //Define the constructor here
    public AbcGeniusPanel() {
        ImageIcon[] alphabets = new ImageIcon[26];
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        //Load the images for alphabet images into the alphabets array using a for loop 
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++) {
            alphabets[i] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Dip\\Desktop\\Java Projects\\AbcGeniusApp\\src\\Alphabets\\" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }
        //Create a JPnael object
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //Set a layoutManager on the panel
        //panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); //This is not workling good
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 13, 5, 5)); //This is good for now
        //Create an array for holdoing the buttons
        buttons = new JButton[26];
        //This Loop will Store the buttons in the buttons array attatching each image for each button
        //Try passing Images inside the JButton parameter later.
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(alphabets[i]);
        }
        // Now Setting up a new Borderlayout so that we can set the whole gridLayout at the botton of the panel
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 0));
        //add the panel to the Border layout
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //Add evenHandling mechanism to all the buttons
        for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
            buttons[k].addActionListener(this);
        }
        for (int count1 = 0; count1 < 26; count1++) {
            panel.add(buttons[count1]);
        }
    }

    //This Method will generate a random Number and return it
    public int random_number() {
        int rand_num;
        Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        rand_num = generator.nextInt(26);
        return rand_num;
    }

    //This method will draw the font on the Panel
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Font font; //Declare Font object here
        font = new Font("Wide Latin", Font.BOLD, 22); //Set font
        super.paintComponent(g); //Ensure the drawing in super class
        g.setFont(font); //Set the font
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        String text = "CLICK ON THE RIGHT IMAGE!"; //Display the text
        g.drawString(text, 255, 20);
    }

    //To draw the picture on the screen we need to override the paint Method
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        //Here, x and y will determine the x and y position os each image
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        // the varibale q is declared above
        for (q = 0; q < 3; q++) //This loop will generate three images on the screen
        {
            if (showImage) {
                x = x + 265; //X-Position of the image
                y = 90;   //Y-Position of the image
                //q is declared as q=0, so this will always be true
                if (w == 1 || q == 0) {
                    g.drawImage(image, x, y, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), null); //This method will put the image on the screen
                    showImage = true;
                    w = 0;
                }
                while (true) //this loop will run anyway
                {
                    //go inside this loop only when the generated random 
                    //doesn't match with the index of the button that was pressed
                    while ((randNumber = random_number()) != index) {
                        index = randNumber; //Now put the randomVlaue in the index
                        this.image = new ImageIcon(imageList[randNumber]).getImage();
                        showImage = true;
                        //make w=1 so that we can break from the outer  loop
                        w = 1;
                        //break from the inner loop
                        break;
                    }
                    //Since we have made the w=1, so we are breaking out of the outer loop
                    if (w == 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        id = 0;
        while (true) {
            //id is set to zero, for example if the button A (buttons[0])is not pressed then it will go below
            //to increase id until it matches the index of the button that we pressed
            if (source == buttons[id]) {
                //get the image of that same index of the buttons and then set the showImage true
                //SO the the paint function above can draw the image
                this.image = new ImageIcon(imageList[id]).getImage();
                showImage = true;
                //save the index of the button that is presed in another variable
                //then break from the while loop
                index = id;
                break;
            } else {
                id++;
                //This is necessary to make sure that id will cross 26
                //becasue we have only 26 letters or the array index is 26
                //so highest value can be 26 only
                id = id % 26;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- Don't directly reference the `src` directory in your code, it won't exist once the program is build. 2- Use `JButton#setIcon` to change the positions of the images as per your requirements...

Answer (score 2):

1. Add 3 JLabels or JButtons (whatever will be displaying the images) into a JPanel container. The JPanel will likely use a `GridLayout(1, 3, horizontal_gap, 0)` layout.
2. Place all images as ImageIcons into an ArrayList.
3. Shuffle the ArrayList when needed
4. After shuffling place the Icons into the JLabels/JButtons in a for loop using the `setIcon(...)` method.

Note that

- your JPanel should override `paintComponent`, not `paint`. The `paint` method is responsible for painting a component's children and borders, and it does not use double buffering by default, making a more dangerous method to override.
- Putting in a `while (true)` loop into your Swing GUI without regard to threading is extremely dangerous.
- Putting this into a painting method such as `paint` is GUI suicide. Never do this since a painting method is a major determinant in the perceived responsiveness of your program. If you slow it down, the program will be perceived as being slow and poorly responsive, and thus it must be lean and **fast** as possible, and you should have painting and only painting code within it.
- Your `paint` method has program logic in it, something that also shouldn't be done. You don't have full control over whether or even **if** a painting method will be called, and so program logic should never be placed inside one of these.
- As MadProgrammer well notes, don't use the src path for your images as this won't exist once you build your program into a jar file. Better to Create a resource directory in the jar file, and to refer to your images as resources, not as files.

Comment: Want to address the `src` reference issue...or are you, like me, pretending it doesn't exist ;) +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: working through his code, and haven't gotten there yet, but will get there.